# Ending of Assassin's Creed: Brotherhood question

Tags: assassins-creed-brotherhood

This is regarding the ending of Assassin's Creed: Brotherhood. I have marked the question below as a spoiler, so please do not hover over it if you haven't played through the game yet!

> At the end of the game, Desmond is forced to kill Lucy. Prior to him stabbing her, you basically button-mash until he makes the strike. Is there an alternate ending or a way to avoid killing her, such as a sequence of buttons to break free?

For context, I have only recently finished Brotherhood, and have not begun Revelations yet, so I'd appreciate any answers that avoid future-game content.

Comment: Also, did you solve all the glyph puzzles? If you haven't do it.

Comment: Yup, solved all of them. That was pretty awesome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> There's no way to avoid that outcome.

Comment: Please use the spoiler tag next time.

Comment: How do I use the spoiler tab?

Comment: I never said spoiler tab.. I said spoiler tag, which I edited in for you.... might help to edit your answer and see the changes I made.

Comment: It's worth noting that specifics about this sequence are all explained in some DLC for Revelations, too.

Comment: My bad. There was no way to edit the comment. I guess I could've deleted and reposted.